# Рамка в виде изображения

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как можно сделать рамку блока в виде изображения, но чтобы с каждой стороны блока было своё изображение.  
У меня получилось сделать слева и справа, а вот сверху и снизу не знаю, как сделать.

Вот так я сделал слева и справа:

```
.info-block:before{content: url(/lk/img/info-l.png);}
.info-block:after{content: url(/lk/img/info-r.png);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-image

http://jsfiddle.net/g8fm6n9h/

http://jsfiddle.net/k3x42r9r/ - последний вариант - с изображениями

Comment: Насколько я знаю, с помощью border-image нельзя сделать с каждой стороны свою картинку.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g8fm6n9h/ может, так?

Comment: Спасибо, большое, отредактируйте ответ пожалуйста на этот ,я отмечаю его как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужны два фоновых изображения, используй `background`:

```
background-image:url('img/1.jpg'), url('img/2.jpg');
background-position:top left, top right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```